# SQL: Left outer join with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

I need to do a left outer join like this:

```
SELECT 
    tblProjects.*, 
    tblNotes.NoteID,
    tblNotes.regDate AS lastUpdatedNote
FROM 
    tblProjects 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tblNotes ON tblProjects.ProjectID = tblNotes.ProjectID
```

But a project can have several notes and in this case im only interested in the one with MAX(regDate) how can i add this condition to the sql above? Or do i have to grab all the notes for each project and filter out the latest in code?

So i only want one row per project and in that row i want the lastUpdatedNote info.

Thx :)

Comment: which database schema is this

Comment: why are you using `LEFT OUTER JOIN`? Looking at the above sql, notes are associated with project. Isn't it?

Comment: select your MAX(regDate) but just do an inner join and group by projectid - I assume you're not interested in projects with no notes, correct?

Comment: append: `AND tblNotes.regDate = MAX(tblNotes.regDate)` (without backquote of course) haven't tested it, just try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MS SQL you can do something like this:

```
SELECT 
    tblProjects.*, 
    tblNotes.NoteID,
    tblNotes.regDate AS lastUpdatedNote
FROM tblProjects 
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 NoteId, regDate
    FROM tblNotes
    WHERE tblProjects.ProjectID = tblNotes.ProjectID
    ORDER BY tblNotes.regDate DESC
) tblNotes
```

Replace with `CROSS APPLY` if you need only those projects that have notes.

or with CTE:

```
WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NoteId ORDER BY RegDate DESC) RowNumber
    FROM tblNotes
)
SELECT tblProjects.*, cte.NoteID, cte.RegDate
FROM tblProjects 
    LEFT JOIN cte on
        tblProjects .ProjectId = cte.ProjectId AND RowNumber = 1
```

Replace with `INNER JOIN` if you need only those projects that have notes.

Comment: A project could have no notes, so it should be LEFT JOIN. (The OP uses it anyway.) And `RowNumber = 1` should be added to the left join condition.

Comment: @Andriy M - Thank you. I updated my answer and commented on that.

Comment: Your left join is still an inner join essentially, because you are filtering on `RowNumber` in the WHERE clause.

Comment: :) Simply `LEFT JOIN cte on tblProjects .ProjectId = cte.ProjectId AND RowNumber = 1`, and you don't need the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Going to try this! Will be back with result! THX

Comment: Cant get any of them to work 
I have tried some stuff on both ways but couldnt get it to work. 
Im using SQL Server 8.0.2039, if that is a reason for failing... 
The errors i get are syntax errors.

Comment: solved it by calling another storedprocedure and storing the result in a temp table. MArking this as the answer as its probably correct.